# Copy-Item and PadLeft

Tags: powershell, copy-item, padleft

I need to retrieve pdf file and copy this pdf file from source to destination. The pdf name are in txt file listspec one number by line :

```
100
200 
204 
79002 
XS002
```

I concatenate the `.pdf` extension

But the pdf files are 001**00**.pdf, 002**00**.pdf, 204**00**.pdf, 79002.pdf, XS002.pdf. I need to Padleft with 0 the pdf file name on 5 positions max.

I use this command :

```
Get-Content $listspec | Foreach-Object{copy-item -Path $source\$_".pdf".PadLeft(5,'0'), -destination $destination -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable +errors}
```

I receive this error :

```
*Copy-Item : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter ' method is not supported.*
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: surround the code that concatenates the pdf extension to the loop variable with parentheses `(` & `)`

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple typo problem. Remove the comma `,` between `-path` and `-destination`.

Instead of this:

`copy-item -Path $source\$_".pdf".PadLeft(5,'0')` , `-destination $destination`

Use syntax like so,

`copy-item -Path $source\$_".pdf".PadLeft(5,'0') -destination $destination`

Comment: I remove comma , between -path and -destination. I receive this error _Copy-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.
At C:\temp\spec\CopySpec.ps1:30 char:49
+ Get-Content $listspec | Foreach-Object{copy-item <<<<  -Path $source\$_".pdf".PadLeft(5,'0') -destination $destinatio
n -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable +errors}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand_

Comment: seems the foreach var is not a string, let me test

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to copy the files specified in `files.txt` to the folder `dest`:

`gc .\files.txt | % { Copy-Item  ($_.padRight(5,"0")+".pdf") -Destination "dest\ " }`

I had to wrap the filename to have it be evaluated prior to passing it to the `Copy-Item` cmdlet

this: **(**`$_.padRight(5,"0")+".pdf"`**)**

Comment: I'm using `gc` alias for `Get-Content` cmdlet and `%` for `ForEach-Object`

Comment: Ok, Vincent it's working. Thanks. `Get-Content $listspec | Foreach-Object{copy-item -Path ($source+$_.PadLeft(5,'0')+'.pdf') -destination $destination -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable +errors}  
`